# Convert map values to plain strings without brackets?

Tags: go

I have a map string that looks like this

```
map[first:[hello] second:[world]]
```

The problem is that when I iterate over it and return the values they return `[hello] [world]` and I want them to just return `hello world`

```
// currentMap is of type map[interface{}]interface{} originally
newStringMap := make(map[string]interface{})

for k, v := range currentMap {
    newStringMap[k.(string)] = v
}

return newStringMap
```

How can this be done?

Comment: That depends on how you're getting the undesired output, which isn't shown here. Please include the code that actually generates the output you're getting.

Comment: What is a "map string"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the below information provided by you:

> when I iterate over it and return the values they return [hello] [world]

It seems that your `currentMap` actually stores string slices `[]string` as values, behind the `interface{}` type. Assuming that above line means that you see this when printing the map using fmt.Println(), or similar functions.

> `map[first:[hello] second:[world]]`

Here's a possible reproduction & solution of your problem::

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    currentMap := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
    currentMap["first"] = []string{"hello"}
    currentMap["second"] = []string{"world"}
    newStringMap := make(map[string]interface{})

    fmt.Println("Problem:")

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", currentMap)

    fmt.Println("\nSolution:")

    for k, v := range currentMap {
        lst, ok := v.([]string)
        //fmt.Println(lst, ok)

        if ok && len(lst) > 0 {
            newStringMap[k.(string)] = v.([]string)[0]
        } else {
            newStringMap[k.(string)] = nil
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", newStringMap)
}
```

Which outputs to:

```
Problem:
map[first:[hello] second:[world]]

Solution:
map[first:hello second:world]
```

Try it here
https://play.golang.org/p/5XAA3m6MDX_b

It's not necessary that the content stored in `currentMap` is always of similar type. (if it is, then why would interface{} ever be used). Which means, don't forget your error-checking. I have tried to cover the same. You may need to add some more, based on the possible `actual types` in the map, similar to this section:

```
if ok && len(lst) > 0 {
    newStringMap[k.(string)] = v.([]string)[0]
} else {
    newStringMap[k.(string)] = nil
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, cheers.